# Distinguish between exception of same type

Tags: c#, .net, exception

What is the best method to distinguish between two exception of the same type but thrown for different reasons.

For example `InvalidOperationException` can be thrown attempting to access an empty sequence, but it can also be thrown when using the Concurrent object (e.g. `BlockingCollection`)

From my reading I've taken the conclusion that using the `BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding()` to signal completion is perfectly fine and as such one would need to catch the Exception and handle appropriately (exit the task for instance)

What is the best way to filter these without having to use the message content?

*Edit*: They both appear to have the same HResult value.

Comment: Have you checked their `InnerException`?

Comment: You can either catch it immediately with a very specific scope and rethrow a custom exception, or you'll have to rely on the error message. Although C#6 has made this slightly less-sucky: http://druss.co/2015/05/c-6-0-exception-filters-try-catch-when/

Comment: @Alex I'll double check if there is an InnerException.  That could be an option for some cases but it's not really the solution

Comment: @Rob as I though.  Thank you for the link, that is interesting news.

Comment: Why does it matter? If you could have handled the case that generated the exception, it would never have been thrown. Thus, even if you could distinguish them, how would that help?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can differentiate between two `Exception`s of the same `Type` **only by the `Message`**.

**However**, you should **not** rely on the `Message` to make `Catch` decisions. The `Message` may be [localized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.message?view=netframework-4.8#notes-to-inheritors) depending on the locale configuration of the system you are executing your code on. This will make your `Catch` `When` block not relevant if the language of the system is different than the language of the `Message` you hard-coded.

The only case where you can use the `Message` is when you are the system administrator and writing a software for a server you will be managing and you are sure that the language you are using will not change in the future (which cannot be guaranteed when you write a software for to run on client devices).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem with Exceptions of the same Type, which i couldn't catch, because they were thrown in a piece of code i don't have access to. My solution was distinguishing by the Source and TargetSite of the exception. It feels kind of like a dirty fix, but it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33592945)

Answer (score 0):

This is an unstable solution (because the source code of .NET can change in the future), but I can't find the other one.

For example, if you want to detect `InvalidOperationException` with this message:
"A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled)."
..., then you can use this code:

```cs
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    string taskErrMsg = null;
    if (exc is InvalidOperationException)
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly sysAsm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.String)); // get System assembly
            System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new("System.Private.CoreLib.Strings", sysAsm);
            taskErrMsg = rm.GetString("Task_Dispose_NotCompleted"); // get the error message in the current language
        }
        catch { }
    }
    if (taskErrMsg is not null && exc.Message == taskErrMsg)
    {
        // if the exception is related to task disposal
    }
    else
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I came up with this solution by looking into the source code of the `Task` class here - https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,29d432e77814898d


You can look up the other message IDs here - https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/artifacts/obj/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/x64/Debug/System.SR.cs,594002b480c91cd7


(I tried to add these as links, but it seems that the code block broke all the text highlighting below it)