# Check localized exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

For an Office Add-in, `ArgumentException` with `"The item with the specified name wasn't found"` message should be handled. An if-check comparing messages works just fine for this purpose as long as a user uses English version of MS Office.

How can I catch the same exception, say in German, if the exception message is translated to `"Das Element mit dem angegebenen Namen wurde nicht gefunden."`?

**Complications:**

1. Inner exception is null in this case.
2. `HResult` of another `ArgumentException "Value does not fall within the expected range"` has the same value.
3. `ParamName` is null in this case.
4. As this runs in UI thread, I cannot change the exception localization.

**Note:** A bit related to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281230/distinguish-between-exception-of-same-type)

Comment: What about `ParamName`? That should be different right?

Comment: It is null in this case, because it is triggered without a value